# How can we add units to grafana email alerts

Tags: grafana

How can we  add units to grafana email/slack alerts

hey, how can we add units to grafana alerts metric like 10GB/100MB instead of just long float value (156543906.909)

check this email alert metrics

```
Metric name                                       Value

test_grafana.1.ik3tyjfv9vg78tjiwwatfxvld          156543906.909

test_prometheus.1.yycb4sn8syr4i90eso9ixzfx4       145992238.545

test_cadvisor.1.rd7leeyt3ycmtjuvlwdmvqcgn         106926824.727
```

Please help us with this query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible at the moment. That feature seems to be not implemented yet. Check this [gitHub issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6511).